# jQuery Mobile and Multiple ajax requests with changePage

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have two different ajax request in a JQM app as below. The first one is executed on a page form submit, data is written to the database, an alert is displayed, and then the user is redirected to the next page where the same sequence occurs.

The first request works fine but the second request executes twice (the alert is displayed twice and database written to twice). If I add a third request, it is executed three times etc etc. What do I need to do to prevent multiple executions?

```
$(document).live('pagebeforeshow', function () {
  $("#Step1").click(function(){

    var formData = $("#step1").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scripts/script.php?type=Step1",
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.status == 'success') {
            alert('success Step1');
            //When finished redirect to the next step
            $.mobile.changePage('#Step2', {transition: "slideup"});
        }             
          else if(data.status == 'error') {
            alert('error');
              $("#notification").text(data.message);
          }
        },           
        //error: onError           
    });

    return false;
  });

  $("#Step2").click(function(){
    var formData = $("#step2").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scripts/script.php?type=Step2",
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.status == 'success') {
            alert('success Step2');
            //When finished redirect to the next step
            $.mobile.changePage('#Step3', {transition: "slideup"});
        }             
          else if(data.status == 'error') {
            alert('error');
              $("#notification").text(data.message);
          }
        },           
        //error: onError
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Accept answers when they are given.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting multiple requests since you run these click bindings every time a page is shown - they run every time pagebeforeshow event is triggered, and so every changePage() you run adds the same function to the element's click callback.

What You need to do is to bind them **once** when your application starts. By having a look at your code I assume your application has multiple pages in the DOM simultaneously  and you change them by $.mobile.changePage() function. If all pages are present, you can bind the click callback once after they have been generated. To be more specific, get rid of the `$(document).live('pagebeforeshow', function () {}` , just bind the click events for the buttons once they exist.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding an event handler to the `pagebeforeshow` event for every page in the DOM, I suggest using the `pageinit` event since it only runs once per page (per load, so if you refresh a page, it'll fire again).

Also, `.live()` is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7, so it's a good idea to start using `.on()`:

```
//run event handler for each pseudo-page as it initializes (runs once per pseudo-page)
$(document).on("pageinit", ".ui-page", function () {

    //bind event handler to #Step1, #Step2 click events
    $(this).find("#Step1").on("click", function () { /*event handler code here*/ });
    $(this).find("#Step2").on("click", function () { /*event handler code here*/ });
});
```

This way you will attach the event handlers only once and you will make sure to attach them to the correct element(s) (if you have multiple pseudo-pages in the DOM at once this makes sure you're getting the correct `#Step1` element).